# Import from Excel Error when querying SQL database via RODBC

Tags: sql, database, r, excel

I'm using `sqlQuery` for submitting  an SQL query to an ODBC database, and try to retrieve the results

The following R script works

```
x = "'2013-12-19'"

sqlQuery(channel,paste("USE [JWFX]

DELETE FROM Currency$
WHERE [Date] = ",x,";

DELETE FROM MktIndex$
WHERE [Date] = ",x))
```

While the following R scritp, whose query properly works on SQL Server does not work when called in R:

```
sqlQuery(channel,
"USE [JWFX] GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1 GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1 GO
INSERT INTO Currency$
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database= C:/Users/admin/Dropbox/SQL Server/DatabaseInput/BBGdata.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Currency$] WHERE Date = 41627');")
```

and returns the following error:

```
[1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[2] "42000 102 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[3] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'USE [JWFX] GO\nEXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1 GO\nEXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1 GO\nINSERT INTO Currency$\nSELECT * FROM \nOPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database= C:/Users/admin/Dropbox/SQL Server/DatabaseInput/BBGdata.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Currency$] WHERE Date = 41627');'"
```

Why this happen? Any hint?

Comment: RODBC isn't likely to support complex stuff like that. I would only count on the basics.

Comment: @joran: I doubt this has anything to do with R. It's likely a limitation of the SQL Server and/or Excel ODBC drivers.

Comment: That's sort of what I meant, but I wasn't very clear about the distinction between RODBC and the driver itself.

Comment: perhaps you just need to add \n.                                   ```DELETE FROM Currency$ \n
WHERE [Date] = ",x,";``` Or just write the code in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include GO in an SQL string submitted via ODBC, it is only used within SQL Server management Studio to separate batches.

In this case the first line `USE [JWFX] GO` is not needed, provided that the connection string point to database JWFX.

Separate the remaining into three different batches and remove the GO statement between them.

Answer (score 0):

By omitting the first part:

```
USE [JWFX] GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1 GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1 GO
```

the query properly works and correcly insert into the database the rows we have selected through SELECT ...